# user input a list of numbers and use it in a Python function

Tags: python, list, function, input, tuples

I am trying to run this function with the following user input structure but cannot get a correct answer:

```
def biggest_number(*args):   
   print (max(args))  
   return max(args)

a = (int(x) for x in input().split())

# 3,4,5

print (biggest_number(a))
```

So far I have tried different type of brackets "(" for tuples and "[" for lists as well as tried converting the strings to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the generator expression using the *splat* operator:

```
print (biggest_number(*a))
```

Although I think you actually want to use a  container such as tuple or list since you can only consume the gen. exp. once so that the next call to `max` after the *print* gives you an **error**:

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Or:

```
a = tuple(int(x) for x in input().split())
```

However, you still need to *unpack* since your function does not take the iterables directly.

Comment: Hi Moses! Thanks for the answer. here is what I get: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(3,4,5)' with the tuple option

Comment: @shaucha Looks like you're giving the wrong input. Your input should be separated by whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with raw_input() instead of input().

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, correct me if I am wrong but looks like raw_input is for Python 2.7 and input is for Python 3.6